# Efficient way to switch body content?

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a way to switch body content for example what I'm using right now is

```
<html>
  <body>
<?php 

  switch( $_GET['view'] ) {
    case "index" :
      include 'main.php';
      break;
  } 
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

As basic as it is, I do NOT like it, and I'm trying to find for a better way to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: [Model-View-Controller maybe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)?

Comment: Why don't you like it? Unless you're using an MVC framework that provides more advanced functionality, this does the job. Just be careful of path injection if you are accepting view names directly from `$_GET`

Comment: There really isn't any other way to do it, aside from if-statements. However, if you're doing multiple pages, a case statement would likely be the better choice.

Comment: @Michael - I did something like this many, many years ago (2005, to be exact), and I'm still wishing I could fully move away from it... `:s`

Comment: [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) is a good framework.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Time to switch to a framework then.

Answer (score 2):

There are, literally, a great deal of ways you can go about doing this. That being said, very few ways scale nicely, and retain a maintainable form. If I were you, I would consider looking into the [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern, and developing along that line. Using a MVC framework (like [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) or [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/)) will make the swapping of Views (your content files) very easy.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are doing it is good if the main.php type files referenced in the cases are static. In that case they should probably be .html files. This is also a good approach if the outside files that you are including are reused in more than one place or reused for different sites. For example, I use an approach like this to include a login form in different places in my sites.

Another way is to build a string in each branch of the case and echo it at the end, outside the switch-case block. This might be easier to understand and maintain if the different pieces are dynamic(i.e. built at the time the page is requested) and fairly short. It would also be preferable to build the output in the same file if all of the options are very similar. Then the variable parts can be parameterized and the parameters set in each branch. Then, after the switch-case, you would build the string with the parameters and output it to the browser.